# secp256k1 private key save to pem file

Tags: ios, swift, private-key, secp256k1

Hi I am doing the save private key of secp256k1 to pem file with Swift.
As I generate the private key, I got a 32 bytes key, somehow in base64 it is "7vInO7T/GBg6bxkr+6W4ESV4UOy6W4E2N4i9fBgMqYM=" which is a quite short string.
I see some example of other private key generated by other languages such as PHP or Scala I can see the private key in PEM file is somehow like this:
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIEEtespOtpvBZFfn+2YX/9WlsRLTb8YSWkfV1IBP+Lz9oAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEun8ex7Yei3nN1mnw2/c9QNwIEzAZ8+upXkN5hgHNgrpn2ufxP8G/byc9
Lx8wKQIXhmCIXMySxUeQUCDzl65trA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
Which is a very long string of base64.
How can I generate such long string and what the rule for it? I mean what should I do to make my quite short base64 string that I can generate to such long string as other languages do?

Comment: Why do you want the output in one format or another? There are unfortunately multiple formats for private keys.

Comment: I have the task of importing the key from PEM file and save the key to PEM file. I have sereral examples of the PEM file generated from other languages and I am trying to figure out how to generate such string like them in Swift.